# Unix command to replace value(s) in several XML files

Tags: xml, unix

I have a query that is I have different XML documents which contain these tags below:

```
  <property name="abcaddress">
        <value>Rt:try:yutt</value>
```

Now I am at the root of the project that is at `/opt/app/pro1` now in side `pro1` there may be many directories which may contain different xml's inside. In some XML documents there may be this tag so I need to search and replace the `<value>` tag with `TEST1`. Finally, after replacement it would look like:

```
<property name="abcaddress">
        <value>TEST</value>
```

Please advise what will be the appropriate Unix command to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

[Perl pie](http://perlpie.com/):

```
perl -pi -e "s/Rt:try:yutt/TEST/g" /opt/app/pro1/*/*.xml
```

Comment: the `perl` command should be available on any Unix system. The command can be run in a bash terminal. Please give me details of your system if you need more details.

Comment: what is "g" is doing at the end

Comment: The "g" replaces all occurrences of the match with the specified substitution in the file. See [this](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers).